# Monodroid samples/ widgets with source code

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am a .NET developer and I am interested in developing android application in C# and I got monodroid.
Is there any source from where I can get the monodroid sample applications [with source code] which would help me to develop the application in monodroid. Or detailed articles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checkout these samples from the [Android site ported to MonoDroid](https://github.com/mono/monodroid-samples) by the Mono team and these [additional samples](https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/MonoDroid101) that include ports from the Android site plus some other native code examples turned into C#. As far as articles go, there isn't too much out there yet due to the fact that MonoDroid is still in developer preview and there is still quite a bit of work and changes being done.  As we get closer to the official release I am sure that will change.  For now the mailing list, IRC and the [MonoDroid.net](http://monodroid.net) website is the best source of info.

Comment: There's not a lot out there yet as the tech is so new in .Net but if you follow the tutorials it's dead easy to get started on building up that community code base! :)

Comment: In case your interested I also created an example for an InfiniteList in Mono Android. http://www.elucidsoft.com/blog/2011/08/31/infinitelistview-mono-android/