# Mono for Android Location using C# & VS 2010

Tags: c#, location, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a simple app to get user coordinates on an Android phone using VS 2010 and Mono for Android.  All samples seem to be in java which, as I'm not a java developer, is confusing.  If anyone has some sample code using ***only*** C# it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This answer seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4724618/635634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a listener by implementing the [ILocationListener](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Locations.ILocationListener) interface. This is a sample for an activity that also acts as a location listener (though it can be a separate class if you want too):

```
[Activity(Label = "Location Demo")]
public class LocationActivity : Activity, ILocationListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);

        var criteria = new Criteria { Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement };
        string bestProvider = locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);

        locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 5000, 2, this);
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
```

I have a similar sample up [here](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/LocationDemo/LocationActivity.cs) that reads in the coordinates and prints them to the screen.

Comment: Excellent - I had found your page previously and all works, or should work if I had a phone to test it on.  As I'm using an emulator I need to set the test location provider (possibly some other stuff too) and I can't get my head around that part at all.  Nevertheless you answered the question perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: You can mock location data in the emulator as well, either through the DDMS tool that comes with the Android SDK or connecting to the emulator using Telnet and using the "geo" command. More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#MockData

Comment: Ah ha, DDMS, another case of RTFM - Thanks again Greg.